# Usage of the u32 integer type in rust

Tags: rust

For all the primitive integer types in Rust, the `from_str_radix` method, which converts a string in the given radix to an integer, takes a `u32` integer as the argument for the radix. Given that the function panics if the radix is not in the range `[2, 36]`, why doesn't `from_str_radix` take a `u8` instead of a `u32`, as a `u8` can already store larger integers than the largest allowed radix?

This sort of thing also occurs in other integer methods such as `pow`. The largest value of a `u8` is `255` and `2^255` is already larger than the maximum value that can be stored by a `u128` (the largest integer type in Rust), so why does the `pow` function take a `u32`, seeing as most `u32` values for the exponent will cause an overflow?

Comment: Might have to do with alignment. An `u32` value is probably guaranteed to be 4-byte aligned, which might matter for the internal operation. The other possible explanation is that people might call it with expressions evaluating to `u32` which would cause a narrowing conversion. A third option is that it's by accident.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [Niko in #22240](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22240#issue-57519003) (emphasis added):

> These are the guidelines that we intend to follow in the standard library. These guidelines are not intended as universal guidelines to be used outside the standard library (though of course one might choose to do so).
>
> 1. Use unsigned values if the value should always be greater than or equal to zero, and signed values otherwise.
> 2. For indices, pointers, or other values which are tied to a data structure whose size is proportional to the size of memory, use `usize` or `isize`.
> 3. For cases where the acceptable domain of a value *perfectly fits* a fixed number of bits, use the appropriate fixed-size type. For example, a method like `write_u16` would take a `u16` argument.
> 4. **Otherwise, use `i32/u32` if the value has a narrow range** and `i64/u64` otherwise.
>
> Examples:
>
> - Vector indices and hashmap lengths use `usize`.
> - The size of a file would be `u64`, as the maximum size of a file is not tied to addressable memory.
> - Something like `write_u16` takes a `u16` (shocker, I know!)
> - **The radix of an integer would use `u32`.**
>
>   - **You might expect `u8`, since a radix higher than 256 is not useful, but the domain of useful radices is actually much smaller than `u8`, so using `u8` isn't providing a meaningful guarantee, and will simply increase friction.**

Comment: I think that your quote is a follow-up of this rule stated previously in the same post (emphasis mine) _"... where the acceptable domain of a value **perfectly fits** a fixed number of bits, use the appropriate fixed-size type."_.

Comment: @rodrigo: Good point; and indeed, number 4 is even more relevant.  I have included a fuller quote.